# want to run multiple commands with single script

Tags: django, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am creating a single script for setup and running whole Django project.

I mentioned three commands in script. which executed one on one....

Commands:

```
subprocess.run(args=['nohup', 'airflow', 'scheduler']) 
subprocess.run(args=['nohup', 'airflow', 'webserver'])
subprocess.run(args=['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

I used nohup for airflow webserver and scheduler to runs on background

All three command runs one by one as per requirement but the problem is when airflow scheduler runs the script stops at point.

Is there any command or something I can used to run all the commands in single script with stop points.

Comment: I think you can run different command at different paths, that way they will not intercept each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the problem with subprocess Popen

```
subprocess.Popen(args=['nohup', 'airflow', 'scheduler']) 
subprocess.Popen(args=['nohup', 'airflow', 'webserver'])
subprocess.Popen(args=['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

This runs all the command one on one in same terminal